Edge extension side panel populating same data to all tabs
I have created edge extension with side panel to show tab specific data but same data getting reflected to all the tabs containing side panel.
Expected : Side panel should show tab specific data.
Example: I have created Sample Extension that displays URL of the page in side panel.
Issue: Seeing same URL in all the tabs side panel.
Code samples
Steps, I followed to implement side panel follows below,
Step 1: "permissions": ["sidePanel", "tabs"]
Step 2: Allows users to open the side panel by clicking on the action toolbar icon
chrome.sidePanel
  .setPanelBehavior({ openPanelOnActionClick: true })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, info, tab) => {
  if (!tab.url) return;
  const url = new URL(tab.url);
  await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
    tabId,
    path: 'sidepanel.html',
    enabled: true
  });
});

